# can't load css form lib/assets and vendor/assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

the rails guide says that,Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets`.

now the `application.css`  in `app/assets` is:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

but the result is that,only the css files in `app/assets` are loaded.so why the css in `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` aren't loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For /lib and /vendor, you need to load them manually by mentioning the name.

```
# vendor/assets/foo.css.scss

# application.css
/= require 'foo'
```

Also, for CSS, I prefer not to use `require_tree` but to require them one by one, as it's hard to control the order of requiring in tree. And the order does matter in CSS.

Comment: but the guide says that the css in  `lib/assets ` and `vendor/assets `will also be included automatically?

Comment: Yes they are included in assets paths but not in the tree. This behaviour is desired. The assets in app are for app, the tree has reason to include them. But the things in vendor are third party's. Most likely you won't need ALL of third party stuff.

Comment: thanks,I got it,so you mean that `= require_tree .` just include the css in `app/assets`,though `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` are  also Pipeline assets path.